# Suggestions for a good Content Formatting Library

Tags: c#, open-source, formatting

I am trying to implement a content formatting feature in my website - that is, I want to let my users type for example [b]bold[/b] or (like SO) * * bold * * and end up with **bold**. I also want support for headers, links, images etc.

The more I'm working on this, the more I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. If possible, I would like to find an OpenSource library that I could use, or at least "borrow" from. So my question is:
**What content formatting library do you recommend? Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), for which there are many open source formatting libraries available.

Comment: Markdown in its original form requires Perl, which did not really comply to my need to use it with ASP.NET C#. However, a couple of Google searches gave me Markdown.NET, which was exactly what I wanted =)